# Movie rent and stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's my question. I want to make a "store" in MySQL where you can rent movies.

I have a table called `Movie`, that has these fields:

```
Movie_ID
MovieName
Shop_ID (FK from the table Shop)
```

The `Shop` table:

```
Shop_ID
ShopName
Location
```

I'm practicing stored procedures, so it has to be done in that. My question is:

How can i check if a given movie is available for rent in fx a store in LA? And how can I tell tell that I want to rent it in a specific period, and then return it to another store, in a different place in town?

Comment: maybe you should create more rows like: available_LA, available_NY... etc. Just use common sense. Are you asking for code or a solution?

Comment: @pattyd Absolutely **not**. You should **not** create a table for every city, you should create a table for all available cities, a table for all available movies, and a relationship table that will tell you which movie is available in which city.

Comment: Agreed with BackSlash.

Comment: @BackSlash ahh, good thinking! I did not say create a table! I said row! But doing it your way would be a much better idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up ... You need to search by a name, and by an association. I'd do it with a WHERE name + WHERE shop in :

```
SELECT Movie_ID
FROM Movie
WHERE MovieName = 'The Matrix'
 AND Shop_ID IN (
  SELECT Shop_ID
  FROM Shop
  WHERE Location = 'NY')
```

Comment: How do i convert this to a stored procedure?

Comment: not sure why you need it as a proc, but the doc is very straightforward : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html